# Can we create a record for Event object through lwc in Salesforce?

Tags: javascript, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc, lightning

This is my js code:

```
var fields = {'OwnerId': user,'CreatedById': user,'WhoId': this.doctorName ,'StartDateTime':this.startDate, 'EndDateTime':this.endDate, 'Departments__c': this.depName, 'Doctor_Name__c': this.doctorName};
var objRecordInput = {'apiName' : 'Event', fields};
// LDS method to create record.
createRecord(objRecordInput).then(response => {
    alert('Event created with Id: ' +response.id);
}).catch(error => {
    alert('Error: ' +JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

I am getting this error:

> Error: {"status":400,"body":{"message":"Object Event is not supported
> in UI API","statusCode":400,"errorCode":"INVALID_TYPE"},"headers":{}}

I have tried using lightning-record-form earlier. I got this same error. That's why I created my own UI, but that is also not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can check list of supported obejcts for [createRecord](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_create_record) in this [All Supported Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_all_supported_objects.htm) documentation.

As you can mention, `Event` object is not listed here.

You'll need to create custom static `Apex` method and call in imperatively from your `js` of `lwc` component, in order to create `Event` from `lwc`.